# Not able to perform query using vertx-db2-client with Spring Boot and getting error

Tags: spring-boot, vert.x

I'm trying to connect and query to DB2 using vertx-db2-client, but it is not working. I'm using Spring Boot 2.6.6 and vertx-db2-client library to perform query in reactive way. I've created a class which implements `CommandLineRunner`

Dependency in my `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-db2-client:4.2.6'
implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-reactive-streams:4.2.6'
```

Below is my `CommandLineRunner` class.

```
import io.vertx.db2client.DB2ConnectOptions;
import io.vertx.db2client.DB2Pool;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.PoolOptions;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.Row;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.RowSet;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.SqlClient;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class DB2DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

  /**
   * Callback used to run the bean.
   *
   * @param args incoming main method arguments
   * @throws Exception on error
   */
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {    

    DB2ConnectOptions connectOptions =
        new DB2ConnectOptions()
            .setPort(50001)
            .setHost("db_host_name")
            .setDatabase("db_name")
            .setUser("username")
            .setPassword("password");

    // Pool options
    PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(5);

    // Create the client pool
    SqlClient client = DB2Pool.client(connectOptions, poolOptions);

    // A simple query
    client
        .query("SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE")
        .execute(
            ar -> {
              if (ar.succeeded()) {
                RowSet<Row> result = ar.result();
                System.out.println("Got " + result.size() + " rows ");
              } else {
                System.out.println("Failure: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
              }

              // Now close the pool
              client.close();
            });
  }
}
```

I'm not seeing any connection issues. The error that I see right after the deployment is below:

```
2022-04-11 15:35:11.740  INFO 2736 --- [           main] c.h.t.p.ServiceApp          : Started ServiceApp in 3.746 seconds (JVM running for 4.719)
Failure: SQLState.NET_VCM_VCS_LENGTHS_INVALID: VCM and VCS lengths are mutually exclusive but both were set: vcsLen=255  vcmLen=12336
```

I'm not sure what is this "Failure: **" means. Can anyone please help me understand this and how to fix. Database connection parameters are correct. I've just masked here. I was following [this](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-db2-client/java/#_getting_started) documentation for the example.

Comment: Can you file an issue on `vertx-sql-client` with all these details?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @tsegismont. I've created a bug for this: https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/4332